# To give unsubscribe link in the mail using sendgrid XSMTPAPI header

Tags: jakarta-mail, sendgrid

Can any one please tell me how to add unsubscribe link in the mail which is send by modifying the header.I am using Sendgrid header XSMTPAPI, although I found a relevant header called subscription track in the filters, but couldn't figure out how to use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would want to have an `X-SMTPAPI` header that looked something like this when broken out:

```
{ 
  filters: { 
    subscriptiontrack: { 
      settings: { 
        enable: 1,
        "text/html": "Unsubscribe <%Here%>", 
        "text/plain": "Unsubscribe Here: <% %>" 
      } 
    } 
  }
}
```

When you're sending the request, make sure you stringify the JSON for the header:

```
X-SMTPAPI: '{"filters":{"subscriptiontrack":{"settings":{"enable":1,"text/html":"Unsubscribe <%Here%>","text/plain":"Unsubscribe Here: <% %>"}}}}'
```

---

Also, as a side note, all of this can be found on the docs page for the `X-SMTPAPI` header:

- http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/index.html
- http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/apps.html

Comment: can you help me in setting X-SMTPAPI in `ruby-on-rails`. I put a question related to this in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18079692/how-to-dynamically-set-unsubscribe-link-in-sendgrid-using-ruby-on-rails