# How to dynamically set unsubscribe link in sendgrid using PHP / Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, smtp, sendgrid, email-headers

I'd like to dynamically set unsubscribe links using Sendgrid in my PHP/Laravel similar to how its been demonstrated with [Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18079692/how-to-dynamically-set-unsubscribe-link-in-sendgrid-using-ruby-on-rails).

I see that I need to set a header with JSON. Can someone help figure out how this header gets integrated with a simple signup confirm code? See below:

```
Mail::send('emails.confirmation', ['user' => $user, 'resend_text' => $resend_text], function ($m) use ($user, $resend_text) {
    $m->to($user->email)->subject('Confirm your email address'.$resend_text);
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up setting the substitution text via [sendgrid.com](https://app.sendgrid.com/settings/tracking) and setting the link in my HTML like this `<a href="UNSUBSCRIBE_LINK">Unsubscribe</a>`. Specifically, on the `subscription tracking` section on sendgrid.com, I set `REPLACEMENT TAG` to `UNSUBSCRIBE_LINK`. So Sendgrid parses your email's HTML and substitutes the hrefs. Pretty cool.